# Bootstrap Carousel - randomize

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an idea but do not know how to execute it.  I am working on a webpage, design in progress, with a bootstrap carousel. What I would like is to have on page load 3 items randomized out of a pool of n amount. That way each time the page is loaded, there is new content.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?
I am fine with using something different then carousel.

Thanks!

Comment: At least show what you have done so far to get further helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you get your items length using jQuery :

```
let items = $('.item').length;
```

then you create a function to get random number depending on your items length using this function:

```
function getRandomInt(items) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(items));
}
```

then you put it in your Bootstrap carousel function :

```
$('#idOfYourCarousel').carousel(Number(getRandomInt(items)));
```

and then you associate it with your click event for example :

```
$('next').click(function(){
   let items = $('.item').length;
   $('#idOfYourCarousel').carousel(Number(getRandomInt(items)));
});
```

Or automatically :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
   let items = $('.item').length;
       $('#idOfYourCarousel').carousel(Number(getRandomInt(items)));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `pool` that has your carousel elements as objects, this will pick 3 random elements from the variable `pool`.

```js
let pool = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4},{id: 5},{id: 6}];
// Number of randoms you want to pick from the pool
let noOfRandoms = 3;

/**
 * Returns a random number between 0 and max (Excluding max)
 */
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function getRandoms() {
  let availableElements = pool;

  let selectedElements = [];
  while (noOfRandoms--) {
    // Get a random integer from 0 to (availableElements.length)
    let selectedIndex = getRandomInt(availableElements.length);
    // Add element at the selectedIndex from availableElements to selectedElements
    selectedElements.push(availableElements[selectedIndex]);
    // Remove the element at selectedIndex from availableElements array
    availableElements.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
  }

  return selectedElements;
}

console.log(getRandoms());
```